# State of identical files being both added and removed

Tags: git

I stumbled upon a weird phenomenon which as far as I can tell can reliably be reproduced using this script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -Rf repo
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
mkdir folder
echo a > folder/a
echo b > folder/b
git add .
git commit -m "First commit."
rm folder/b
echo c > folder/c
git add .
git commit -m "Second commit."
cd folder
git checkout `git log --pretty=format:%H | tail -1` .
echo "###################################################################"
git status
echo "###################################################################"
rm *
git checkout `git log --pretty=format:%H | head -1` .
echo "###################################################################"
git status
echo "###################################################################"
git add .
echo "###################################################################"
git status
echo "###################################################################"
```

The hashes are just to make it easier to see where one `git status` ends and another one starts. I put it on pastebin so we can refer to the line numbers more easily: https://pastebin.com/z8GgDpfw

It's output is:

```
$ ./script.sh Initialized empty Git repository in /[...]/repo/.git/
[master (root-commit) 165986a] First commit.
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 folder/a
 create mode 100644 folder/b
[master 241e479] Second commit.
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 folder/b
 create mode 100644 folder/c
###################################################################
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   b

###################################################################
###################################################################
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   b

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    b

###################################################################
###################################################################
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
###################################################################
```

`b` is shown as both added and deleted for no apparent reason: It is exactly the same in the repo, the index, and the working tree. `git add .` magically cleans `git status`.

Is this intended behavior? If so: Why? Why not just show a clean `git status` without `git add .` having to be executed first?

Comment: Can you shorten your commands to only show the relevant output, i.e. the portion where the file is both there and deleted? Also, would you mind writing everything explicit (without backticks)?

Comment: @AnoE It's preferable to have the complete commands to reproduce the problem. It helped me immensely to understand what was going on.

Comment: @AnoE Most of the output shows exactly that. The backtick commands figure out the commit IDs. Those are different on every execution of the script because those executions happen on different times and have the names and email addresses of different people in them (depending on the git configuration of the computer it's run on). If I'd put my commit hashes there, it wouldn't work on your computer.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. Was parsing in my head, not close to a shell right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is added a new file to the staging area, and then deleted it from the working copy. That's pretty easy to replicate.

```
$ git init repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/repo/.git/
$ cd repo/
$ touch this
$ git add this
$ rm this
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   this

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    this
```

`touch this` created a file in the working copy. `git add this` copied it to the staging area. `rm this` deleted the file from the working copy *but it's still in the staging area*.

If I `git commit` right now, `this` will be committed, despite it being missing from the working copy. `git commit` turns whatever's in the staging area into a commit.

Most of the time you don't need to worry about the staging area, but it becomes *very* handy when you have to pull apart a complicated change into multiple commits. Commands like `git add -p` become very powerful tools for creating smaller, more focused commits.

---

What you're running into is the difference between the "working copy" and the "staging area" (also known as the "index" or the "cache"). The working copy are the actual files on disk, like `folder/b`.

The staging area is where the next commit is built. You can think of it like a temp directory. `git add` copies files from the working copy into the staging area. `git commit` takes whatever's in the staging area and turns it into the next commit.

This is why you can have "staged" and "unstaged" changes to the same file. That means the version in the staging area is different from the version on disk which is different from the version in the previous commit (`HEAD`).

Comment: That's not what's happening. After execution of line 14 (see the pastebin link for line numbering), the staging area is clean. The `git status` which shows the phenomenon happens in line 23 which is before `git add` is executed the next time after line 14 in line 25.

Comment: Ah, line 16 automatically adds the changes the checkout causes to the staging area, right?

Comment: @UTF-8 Yes, the first `git checkout` is the equivalent to recreating b from an old commit and then adding it to the staging area. `rm *` is deleting all the files *in the working copy*, but b in the staging area is left alone. The second `git checkout` brings a and c back, but not b. Part of the confusion might be because there's several rather different forms of `git checkout`. You're using the `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...` form which is rather different from the others.

Comment: Ah, that small "to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree." in the man page. Thanks! :)